# Filter data from Json to new Array which can be used in HighChartsJs

Tags: javascript

I am currently working with HighCharts JS. For data to be shown in HighCharts, I must have the final data as follows:

```
[
  {
    name: 'Performing',
    data: [1941404, 1028717, 697370, 0, 0, 0]
  },
  {
    name: 'Non performing',
    data: [0, 0, 0, 1759908, 890857, 280235]
  },
  {
    name: 'Substandard',
    data: [0, 0, 863825, 0, 0, 0]
  },
  {
    name: 'Written-off',
    data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 77146]
  }
]
```

'Data' is an array of 6 objects which populate the xAxis of the chart.

However, I have the following data which is being supplied via MongoDb

```
const chartData = [
  {
    "_id": {
      "data": "90 - 180",
      "status": "Non Performing"
    },
    "value": 1759908
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "data": "360",
      "status": "Written-off"
    },
    "value": 77146
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "data": "360",
      "status": "Non Performing"
    },
    "value": 280235
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "data": "30 - 90",
      "status": "Substandard"
    },
    "value": 863825
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "data": "30 - 90",
      "status": "Performing"
    },
    "value": 697370
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "data": "180 - 360",
      "status": "Non Performing"
    },
    "value": 890857
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "data": "0 - 30",
      "status": "Performing"
    },
    "value": 1028717
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "data": "0",
      "status": "Performing"
    },
    "value": 1941404
  }
]
```

I need to filter through the latter code so it ends up like the former code. It is very important that in the data array, we end up with 6 objects to make sure we populate the entire xAxis of Highcharts, hence we see lots of zeros, where no data was supplied.

I really hope this clears things up. Thank you to all those who have help. I apologise for being so vague from the offset.

QUICK NOTE The order of the data array is as follows: 0, 0-30, 30-90, 90-180, 180-360, 360

**EDITTED**

So this is the code I am using at the moment:

```
const data = this.chartData
        let series

        series = Object.values(data.reduce((acc, currVal) => {
          acc[currVal._id.status] = acc[currVal._id.status] || { 
            name: currVal._id.status, 
            data: [] 
          };

          acc[currVal._id.status].data.push(currVal.totalBookValue) //push the year to data array after converting the same to a Number

          return acc //return the accumulator
        }, {}))
```

This kind of works, but its not populating the Data array with 6 elements.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: Could you elaborate litle more why 6 elements (we end up with 6 objects, you said, but i see 4) in data array? Also, you already asked same question. Did you try some of the posted solutions?

Comment: I must admit I am in a little distress, as I am having problems. This is what I have so far

const data = this.chartData
        let series

        series = Object.values(data.reduce((acc, currVal) => {
          acc[currVal._id.status] = acc[currVal._id.status] || { 
            name: currVal._id.status, 
            data: [] 
          };

          acc[currVal._id.status].data.push(currVal.totalBookValue) //push the year to data array after converting the same to a Number

          return acc //return the accumulator
        }, {}))

Comment: This kind of works but its not incorporating zeros into my data array.

So the data array needs to have 6 elements, as it will populate the xAxis in HighCharts. If there isnt 6 elements, then it pretty much screws up everything in HighCharts :(

Comment: Ok, so 6 is constant, but order of zeroes seems tricky...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem can be solved via a bit of traversal using [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to reach `object` `form` and [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to return to `array` `form` (assuming the `0` to `360` list you posted is complete).

See below for a practical example.

```js
// Input.
const input = [
  {
    "_id": {
      "data": "90 - 180",
      "status": "Non Performing"
    },
    "value": 1759908
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "data": "360",
      "status": "Written-off"
    },
    "value": 77146
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "data": "360",
      "status": "Non Performing"
    },
    "value": 280235
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "data": "30 - 90",
      "status": "Substandard"
    },
    "value": 863825
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "data": "30 - 90",
      "status": "Performing"
    },
    "value": 697370
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "data": "180 - 360",
      "status": "Non Performing"
    },
    "value": 890857
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "data": "0 - 30",
      "status": "Performing"
    },
    "value": 1028717
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "data": "0",
      "status": "Performing"
    },
    "value": 1941404
  }
]

// Depth.
const depth = ['0', '0 - 30', '30 - 90', '90 - 180', '180 - 360', '360']

// Object Form.
const objectform = input.reduce((accumulator, x) => {
  const { _id, value } = x // _id. Value.
  let { data, status } = _id // Status.
  status = status.toLowerCase() // Lower Case.
  const point = {...accumulator[status], [data]: value} // Data.
  return {...accumulator, [status]: point} // Update + Return Accumulator.
}, {})

// Output.
const output = Object.keys(objectform).map((key) => {
  return {
    name: key, // Name.
    data: depth.map((frame) => objectform[key][frame] || 0) // Data.
  }
})

// Log.
console.log(output)
```